# Why r.walk calculates different cumulative cost depending on calculation direction

Tags: grass-gis, optimization

I have two points A and B. If I calculate cumulative costs from A to B respectively from B to A I expect the same cumulative costs at the arrival points. Take into account that the walk_coeff are set symmetrically:

- From A to B: a,b,c,d=0.72,6,10,-10
- From B to A: a,b,c,d=0.72,10,6,-6

Details for abcd you find under [r.walk](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.walk.html)

As the uphill/downhill coefficients are symmetrical, theoretically the cumulative costs should be identical at the arrival point. It doesn't matter if travel from A to B or from B to A. Interestingly the cumulative costs do differ!

If I calculate at a resolution of 1 m the difference is relatively small, if I calculate at a resolution of 10 m the difference can become big.

What I tried:

- I tried to place A and B to the center of the next pixel
- I tried the option -k (Knight)

Any ideas?

```
r.walk elevation=dem@PERMANENT friction=cost@PERMANENT output=cumCostUp outdir=movDirUp start_points=start@PERMANENT stop_points=stop@PERMANENT max_cost=10000000 null_cost=16000 walk_coeff=0.72,6,10,-10 lambda=0.2 --overwrite
v.what.rast map=stop@PERMANENT raster=cumCostUp@PERMANENT column=cumCost
r.walk elevation=dem@PERMANENT friction=cost@PERMANENT output=cumCostDown outdir=movDirDown start_points=stop@PERMANENT stop_points=start@PERMANENT max_cost=10000000 null_cost=16000 walk_coeff=0.72,10,6,-6 lambda=0.2 --overwrite
v.what.rast map=start@PERMANENT raster=cumCostDown@PERMANENT column=cumCost
```

Some additional information:

- dem and cost have a resolution of 10m. Pixels are tapped to 10 m (-tap from GDAL)
- start and stop coordinates are in X and Y: n*10 + 5
- The difference becomes minimal with very small resolutions x=1 or x=0.1 (r.region res=x). So the mirroring of abcd is correct.
- If b=c=d=0 there isn't anymore an asymmetry.
- If uphill and downhill cost are set both to 6 there is still an asymmetry.

Sample data you find here:
[Sample-Data](https://info.skitourenguru.ch/download/data/rwalk_data.zip) with EPSG=21781.

Bug-Report on [GRASS-Github](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/2496)

Comment: Please look at the definition of abcd in [r.walk](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.walk.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**c must be equal to d.**

The following example produces a symmetrical result for all resolutions r, also for r=10:
From A to B: a,b,c,d=0.72,6,-10,-10
From B to A: a,b,c,d=0.72,10,-6,-6

Answer (score 0):

The uphill slopes going from A to B will, of course, become downhill when going from B to A. There is only one coefficient `b` for uphill slopes, but the downhill direction gets split depending on `moderate downhill` or `steep downhill`. So the different `c` and `d` coefficients will, I think, cause the difference you are seeing.

Comment: The mirroring is correct! Look at the definition in r.walk. b is uphill, c=-d is downhill. Take into account, that the difference in the cumulative cost becomes minimal the higher the resolution is set with r.region res=x. With x=0.1 the difference is almost none. With x=10 the difference is relatively big. Working with x=0.1 is not realistic.